# stdClass Object ( [jsonrpc] => 2.0 [id] => 1 [error] => stdClass Object ( [code] => -32000 [message] => unknown account ) )

Tags: polygon, php

Why Am I Getting This Error In

'2.0',
        'id' => 1,
        'method' => 'eth_sendTransaction',
        'params' => array(
            array(
                'from' => '0x',
                //privateKeyToAddress($privateKey),
                'to' => $toAddress,
                'value' => '0x' . dechex($amount),
                'gasPrice' => '0x' . dechex(1000000000),
                'gas' => '0x' . dechex(21000),
            ),
        ),
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => json_encode($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return json_decode($result);
}

function privateKeyToAddress($privateKey) {
    $publicKey = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i result . "\n";
?>